# Dynamic validation using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, validation

I need your help. I need to create a validation framework for complex form which will be generated dynamically.
For instance, user selects some Template he wants to change, then he receives a list of fields to be filled with data. Number of fields can reach up to 150.
There will be few types of validation rules

- Regular expresions
- Is field mandatory
- data type - string, numeric or alphanumeric (can be validated with RegExp)

All the rules for each field will be stored in the database.
The complexity is that each field may have it's own regular expression, therefore validation error messages are also different. I have attached image describing how the control will look:

[image: Fields]

I'm thinking on using JQuery framework and assign each control to be validated using the attribute, but not sure if this task could be done using the JQuery.

Will appreciate any advices on this!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the ASP.NET validators... you can use a `RegularExpressionValidator` and set the `ValidationExpression` from the code behind, etc. This will cover the client-side validation, and you'll need the server-side validation in any scenario anyway.

Comment: Please don't tag spam the question.  If you want to build your own jQuery validation function, then this is not about the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] plugin.  Thanks.  Edited.

Comment: jquery.validate can do that. Based on the meta data that you have on you DB you can dynamically build client rules to be applied